# OpenCV image stitching never finishes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Bit of an odd problem:

cv2.Stitcher_create() from 4.1 and cv2.createStitcher() from 3.4.5 both fail to run with the images provided.

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2

im1 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\David\\Pictures\\koala\\g1.jpg")
im2 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\David\\Pictures\\koala\\g2.jpg")

print("Stitch create")
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create()
print("Stitch begin")
(status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch([im1, im2])
print("Stitch end")
```

The code will never progress past the stitcher.stitch function call. TaskManager tells me that python is maxing out a single core, so it's doing something, but with 2x 140kb images, I don't expect this to take more than, what, 3-4 seconds?

I've tried running the above code in jupyter lab, ipython, and just straight through a console. I've tried making new virtual environments using pipenv and stripping back all the packages to run at the bare minimum. I've tried this with 8bit .tif files, .png files, .jpg files, different images too, and nothing seems to work.

Is something wrong with my graphics driver?

Comment: I was able to run your code but I get status = 1 which corresponds to `ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS`. Typically this error occurs if there are not enough keypoints detected in your input images to construct the panorama. The code ran instantly for me.

Comment: That's what worries me - this seems like a system specific thing that I'm having trouble with. Ty for trying!

Comment: It's most likely some hardware issue on your end. You would also need to give it more input images once you get the hardware issue fixed

Comment: I'll try updating my graphics card drivers and report back; I know that you can pass `False` into the `stitch()` call to disable GPU processing, but that doesn't help here

Comment: Updated my graphics driver, tested - no luck. Disabled my graphics card in device manager, tested - no luck

Comment: Tried a full system re-install. No luck. Works on my laptop, though. Questioning sanity.